# Как передать значение из одной функции в другую?

Tags: c#

```
public string Auth(string Login, string Password){
                ...  
                return auth_key; // возвращаемое после выполнения значение типа string
            }

public void Send(string dist, string fileName, string auth_key){
              // здесь нужно использовать полученный auth_key 
        }
```

Были мысли вызвать функцию Auth в Send, но я уверен, что есть решения и получше.

upd: **желательно** оглашать идею, в которой обе функции выполняются отдельно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вызвать и в функции, не вижу в этом ничего плохого.

Также можно сохранить результат в переменную:

```
var key = Auth(string, string);
Send(string, string, key);
```

---

**UPDATE:** Окей, немного подведу код к вашей ситуации, но принцип остался тот же.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private string _key;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Auth(string Login, string Password)
    {
        string auth_key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return auth_key;
    }

    public void Send(string dist, string fileName, string auth_key)
    {
        if (auth_key != null)
        {
            var a = dist + fileName + auth_key;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _key = Auth("login", "qwerty");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Send("dist", "filename", _key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Важно, чтобы функция Auth выполнилась отдельно от функции Send, то есть сначала выполнить Auth нажатием на button1, а потом, к примеру, выполнить Send нажатием на button2.

Comment: @emoxypine, хорошо, значит мой вариант вам подходит. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: разве в вашем примере не выполняется Send путём выполнения Auth? Это же эквивалентно записи: Send(string, string, Auth(string, string)), разве нет?

Comment: @emoxypine Да, эквивалентен, но сохранение результата в переменную позволяет вызвать эти функции в разное время и в разной последовательности. Обновил ответ.